# How to decide between adding reps or adding weight?

Tags: push-ups

If I feel comfortable with, for example 15 push-ups, should I start making them harder (legs elevated), or add some more to these 15?

If I add reps now, when should I add weight? And if I add weight, when should I add reps?

Especially I want to know what target I should set.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goal.

If you want to be able to do 500 push-ups in a row someday, you'd want to add reps. If you want to get stronger, you'd want to add weight.

If you want to grow in size, you'd want to add weight. If you'd want to train for endurance, you'd be better off adding reps.